# Expanding variables in IF statements in batch

Tags: batch-file

So I need to see if a string contains something. I was thinking, you know how you can do `set VAR=%VAR:-=_%` to target certain things inside the variable and change them with the set command. Well, is there a way I can do this with "IF" statements?.
Example of what it might look like:
`if %VAR%==%VAR:word% echo yes`
This command doesn't actually work but if it did, it would look to see if %VAR% contains "word" anywhere in it.

Comment: The `SET` command has nothing to do with string substitution or substrings.  They both can be done anywhere in a batch file. The CMD parser reads a line of code.  Expands the variables and then executes the line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, but you've only got half of a valid string substitution command, which isn't causing a syntax error, but it *is* causing a flow in the logic: right now you're comparing `%VAR%` to a variable that the interpreter can't access.

If you use string substitution to remove the word you're looking for and then compare that to the original variable, you can use an `if not` statement to determine if the variable was updated by the substitution.

```
if not "%var%"=="%var:word=%" echo yes
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this method will be case insensitive.

Comment: Yes, @T3RR0R, but this can easily be changed to become case-sensitive: `if not "%VAR%"=="%VAR:word=%" if "%VAR%"=="%VAR:word=word%" echo yes`…

Comment: Im fine with it being case sensitive and if i wanted to not be, I would just make all the characters in the variable lowercase.